# How to migrate client db with entity framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, migrate, localdb

I use code first approach with MicroSoft local-db. Until now, only I developed and used my program. When the model changed I used add-migration and Update-Database in package manager console. No problem here.

Now others start to use the program. I use ClickOnce deployment. When there is a new version from the program, the migrated db is distributed.

I want to migrate the db of the client, client data should not be lost. Should I somehow migrate from the program, or ClickOnce should take care of it? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the migrations when the application starts.

> If you are deploying your application you may want it to automatically
> upgrade the database (by applying any pending migrations) when the
> application launches. You can do this by registering the
> MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer. A database
> initializer simply contains some logic that is used to make sure the
> database is setup correctly. This logic is run the first time the
> context is used within the application process (AppDomain).

[Automatically Upgrading on Application Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#automatically-upgrading-on-application-startup-migratedatabasetolatestversion-initializer)